# Insert Statement Check Is NULL SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, null, case

My small SQL query is just importing data from an old database to a new one. My new database does not allow `ProjectNo`, `ProjectName` or `LeaderID` to be a `NULL` value, so my code needs to check if the value is `NULL` and if it is, add in the default values for `ProjectName` and `LeaderID` (`ProjectNo` is the primary Key of the old table, so cannot be `NULL`).

As far as I can tell, I have written the case statement correctly but I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProjectName', table
>   'ERP.dbo.Project'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I am using SQL Server 2008 as well

```
INSERT INTO [ERP].[dbo].[Project] ([ProjectID], [ProjectName], [LeaderID])
   SELECT 
       ProjectNo, 
       CASE 
          WHEN ProjectName IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' 
       END, 
       CASE 
          WHEN ProjectLeaderID IS NULL THEN 1 
       END 
   FROM 
       Multitech.dbo.Projects
GO
```

Comment: Use ISNULL(col, value)

Comment: Is there a reason why my code didn't work though? Is it because the table has the 'No null values' restriction? The reason I ask is because I did a similar query without the restriction on a different table and it worked fine

Comment: Change to `CASE WHEN ProjectName IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE ProjectName END`

Comment: You can solve this in many ways ISNULL, COALESCE ...

Comment: @AaronTroeger The reason it didn't work was because you were missing the `else` part so the rows that actually had values got their values replaced with nulls.

Comment: @jpw Ahhh I see, Thank you for clearing that up

Comment: if you do not use ELSE in your case statement, sql server uses the default ELSE and default for ELSE is NULL.

Comment: You should user the ANSI standard `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
 INSERT INTO [ERP].[dbo].[Project]
       ([ProjectID]
       ,[ProjectName]
       ,[LeaderID])
 SELECT ProjectNo,
       ISNULL(ProjectName, 'Unknown'),
       ISNULL(ProjectLeaderID, 1)
 FROM Multitech.dbo.Projects
```

Add missing ELSE and your code will work too.  [CASE documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> ELSE else_result_expression
>
> Is the expression returned if no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE. **If this argument is omitted and no comparison operation evaluates to TRUE, CASE returns NULL**. else_result_expression is any valid expression.

```
 INSERT INTO [ERP].[dbo].[Project]
       ([ProjectID]
       ,[ProjectName]
       ,[LeaderID])
 SELECT ProjectNo,
        CASE WHEN ProjectName IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE ProjectName END,
        CASE WHEN ProjectLeaderID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE ProjectLeaderID END
 FROM Multitech.dbo.Projects
```

Comment: Ok cool. I used your original suggestion of ISNULL which worked very well. Thank you for taking the time to also explain why it didn't work